# How to tell when a pepper is ripe?

Tags: vegetables

I just started a raised bed garden.

I know when tomatoes are ready to be picked, but how do I know when my one pepper is ready for picking?

[image: pepper]

Comment: What's the pepper's variety name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly when the pepper had reached it's maximum size. Some peppers also change colors. There stem coming off of the fruit will turn slightly brown. Also hardness is a factor. If it is starting to soften, then you know it is ready to be picked.

Comment: And (IIRC, I don't like them so I don't grow them) no normal bell pepper is a green pepper (some of the hot peppers are) - they are just literally picked underripe and marketing has caused them to be an accepted things in parts of the world.

Comment: When picked "green" they have a different flavor than when ripe ( red, or yellow, or other color).so it is more a factor of what flavor you prefer as to when to pick.